# How to calculate the species richness of multi polygons by rasterizing them first?

Tags: r, polygon, r-sf, rasterize

I have a shape file of 4 phylum (4 polygons for each class). Each  contain multiple species range inside it. Means I have a data of almost 200 species in these 4 polygon. My data look like this (figure attached below). I got this data from IUCN and clip it for my study region. Link of dataset is https://www.iucnredlist.org/resources/spatial-data-download

[image]

I want to calculate the species richness for each grid cell of (1km by 1km) rasterizing them in R. Means how many total species in each grid cell like the figure attached below.

[image]

If combined richness is not possible, single like reptiles richness can also work for me and so on. I want to do analysis in R.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(raster)
library(sf)

poly <- st_read("directory.shp")

# Creating a raster 
## Write the rows column of polygonn and xmn, xmx, ymn, ymx according to your country data    

r <- raster(nrows=, ncols=, xmn=, xmx=, ymn= , ymx=, 
        crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0", 
        resolution = 0.008333333, vals=NULL)

a <- rasterize(poly, 
     r,
     field = "binomial",
     fun = function (x, ...) length(unique(na.omit(x))))
```